# How to update a value in reactjs component from outside react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to the technology reactjs. I would like to know how I can show a value from text input which is not rendered using react to  a react component which is simply a label which shows that value. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to provide us with some more detail explaining how these two things should interact. For example, when the input changes, should the label update? Also, show us what you've got so far, or make a start by creating a label component.

Comment: It needs more details, can you add some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call the javascript from the React component.  E.g.

```
const value = document.getElementById('text').value;
```

Here's a fiddle with it all working.

https://jsfiddle.net/ht7tzn5k/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what i want exactly.